# Number of ways of selecting one or more disjoint two-element subsets from a set with $n$ elements

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> I have the equation for $n$ choose $k$ as:
>   $$\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

However, this only works for the disjoint pairs which completely fill the original set.  Is there a way to modify this to include all unique subsets of possible omitted disjoint pairs, without overlapping?

Edit: To add to this, I believe the combinations for a set of 6 should number 60 (though I did this by hand so I may have missed some,) hopefully the actual set will help clear up any potential failings in my communication of the question:

```
12 34 56
12 35 46
12 36 45
13 24 56
13 25 46
13 26 45
14 23 56
14 25 36
14 26 35
15 23 67
15 26 37
15 27 36
16 23 45
16 24 35
16 25 34
12 34
12 35
12 36
13 24
13 25
13 26
14 23
14 25
14 26
15 23
15 24
15 26
16 23
16 24
16 25
23 45
23 46
23 56
24 35
24 36
24 56
25 34
25 36
25 46
26 34
26 35
26 45
34 56
35 46
36 45
12
13
14
15
16
23
24
25
26
34
35
36
45
46
56
```

Comment: To clarify, do you wish to count the number of ways one or more disjoint two-element sets can be selected from a set with $n$ elements?

Comment: This is the sequence https://oeis.org/A001189

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Right, unique subsets of disjoint two-element sets from a set with n elements.

Comment: @Crostul I'm not seeing it in that link.

Comment: @Crostul Would it be possible to post the equation?  I can't make sense of that.

Comment: Well, it seems there is no nice formula. Only recursive ones, or formulas of the generating function.

Comment: The answer for this particular example is actually $75$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig The equation which the answerer provided gives 60, which is the same I got by hand.  Which 15 did I miss?

Comment: Yo missed $12~45$, $12~46$, $12~56$, $13~45$, $13~46$, $13~56$, $14~35$, $14~36$, $14~56$, $15~34$, $15~36$, $15~46$, $16~34$, $16~36$, $16~45$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OEIS the sequence is https://oeis.org/A001189. The nicest formula seems to be
$$a_n=\sum_{j = 1}^{n/2} \frac{n!}{(j!(n-2j)!(2^j))}$$

For a recursive formula,
$$\begin{cases} a_1=0\\a_2=1 \\ a_{n}= a_{n-1}+ (n-1)(a_{n-2}+1) \qquad n>2\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks!  I worked out up to n=6 by hand before you posted this and this looks like it matches.

Comment: Actually you made a mistake in your computations by hand. The correct result for $n=6$ is $75$ (as in the link is said). You forgot 15 combinations among those formed by two couples, e.g. 12 45 , 12 46, 12 56, 13 45 , 13 46 , 13 56 and so on.

Comment: I honestly don't know how Mathematica gave me 60 the first time I typed in this equation, but it is saying 75 now (well, 76 because I added a 1+ to the start of the equation for the case where no matches are made.)  Thanks.